# Not able to receive different regional language text from JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I have an Android activity containing a `TextView` which receives the text value from a servlet. The text value will be requested by the activity for which the servlet responds. I am trying to have the text value in different a regional language. Lets say ***Tamil***, which is a regional language in **India**.

I have the text value for the Android activity's `TextView` in the database which the servlet fetches and sends to the activity. I am using MySQL database which can hold a **Tamil** language text and even the servlet is able put the **Tamil** language text into the `JSONObject`.

The problem occurs on the receiveing side (i.e) on the android activity where the `JSONObject` on parsing gives *Question mark(?)* symbol

If I give the text value for the `TextView` statically, It works fine.

Any Suggestions???

Here is the code of **AllAsyncTask.java** from which I receive the text value from the servlet

AllAsyncTask.java

```
    public class AllAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

    String httpPostStr, res;
    Context context;
    String textValue;

    public AllAsyncTask(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CategoriesActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.TEXT_VALUE, textValue);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void postData(String valueToSend)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Constants.GatewayUrl);

        try
        {
            StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(valueToSend);
            httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpPostStr = httpPost.toString();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            res = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
            textValue = jsonObject.getString(Constants.TEXT_VALUE);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some code ? It could help :)

Comment: @MalteseFalcon I have added the code :)

Comment: `new StringEntity(valueToSend, "UTF-8");` (could matter)

Comment: could be from your server, too. How do you verify that the server sends the right thing?

Comment: if it works statically, then it might be because of the AsyncTask class, it runs on a different Thread.

Comment: @njzk2 I debugged and found bro. The server sends the text value in **Tamil** only. :)

Comment: @MerveSahin may I know in what way does the `AsyncTask` affect the language support?

Comment: @JoopEggen, what would you suggest me instead of `new StringEntity(valueToSend, "UTF-8");`

Comment: @joshua think I misunderstood you're question then

Comment: @Joshua if new StringEntity with UTF-8 did not work, I do not know. Did you try it. Without "UTF-8" it sends in Latin-1 and you'll get ? for Tamil chars.

Comment: @JoopEggen I already tried your suggestion, no changes :(

Comment: @MerveSahin that's ok :)